# How can I display my sorted array, names from binary file?

Tags: java, sorting, binaryfiles

I am having trouble with displaying my sorted array. I have a list of names that I sorted using different sorting algorithms. It is sorted when I use my own created string array. But if I try to sort an array that I imported from a file, it gives me the names in Binary form.

```
   //Read the names into an Array

      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
      List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
      while ((names = br.readLine()) !=null)
      {
        list.add(names);
      }

       br.close();
      String[] name= list.toArray(new String[0]);



    BufferedReader user = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 

    //Sort the array first


    //When i write this, it does not sort it, it just gives me names     //with no space 
    InsertionSort.insertionSort(name);

    System.out.println("\n Sorted Order:");
    for(String n : name)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, n);



    //Ask the user for name to search
    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a name to search for: ");
    String Name= user.readLine();

    user.close();
```

Comment: What is `InsertionSort.insertionSort` ?